# NSLog crashing app using 3.1.3 software

Tags: iphone, nslog, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

the other day I had a bug submitted for my app from a user on an ipod touch with 3.1.3 software. It was a strange bug as no-one else has submitted it yet.

Long story short, it appears that anywhere where I have NSLog() in code it will actually crash the app. I tried stripping out ALL the code other than NSLog(@"hello") and running on my iphone (3.1.3) it indeed did crash. I removed the NSLog and it worked.

Has anyone else had this problem??

PS) I am now aware that we shouldn't release an app with NSLog still in use... so they've all gone now!

Comment: Most likely it is something else and not NSLog -- I have some shipping apps with NSLog and they don't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrap all of my NSLog method calls within a #if DEBUG statement to avoid this situation.

Comment: I've also had this issue, I switched to printf(@""); for a while. - I DON'T recommend this!